# Auto scroll to last row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I'm working on a simple table using [nicescroll plugin](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll).

On load the table auto scroll to bottom, also, I added a button which adds a new row and scroll to bottom too.

my problem is when I added a new input field that generate a rows base from user input, it wont scroll to the last row, some times it bounce in the middle.

Hope you help me.

Thanks

here is my [sample code](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/gKQmvx)

```
// add scroll

$('tbody').niceScroll({autohidemode: false});

// add 1 row
$('button').click(function(){

        var rowCount = $('table > tbody tr').length + 1;

    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>item'+ rowCount +'</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td></tr>');

  $('tbody').animate({
  scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);

});

// scroll to bottom on load
$('tbody').animate({
  scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);

// generate rows
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $('table tbody tr').remove();
  $('tbody').animate({
  scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);

  var rowCount = $('table > tbody tr').length + 1;  
    for(var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++ ){
     $('tbody').append('<tr><td>item'+ i +'</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td></tr>'); 
    }

});

// clear value on input field
$('input').click(function(){
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: That's working if you let animation run (without any other action after typing a number of row to generate), I think code queue animation.

Comment: looks like it wont work if I add two digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only change a bit of your js code

> Way 1

```
...
// generate rows
$('input').keyup(function(){
  // Clean table
  $('table tbody tr').remove();
  // Add new rows
  var rowCount = $('table > tbody tr').length + 1;  
  for(var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++ ){
     $('tbody').append('<tr><td>item'+ i +'</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td></tr>'); 
  }
  // Then stop previous anim with clean anim queue (added by every key typed in input) and finally add new anim
  $('tbody').stop(true, false).animate({
      scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
  });
});
...
```

> Way 2

```
...
// generate rows
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $('table tbody tr').remove();  
  var rowCount = $('table > tbody tr').length + 1;  
  for(var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++ ){
    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>item'+ i +'</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td><td>items</td></tr>'); 
    // Animate during row adding  
    $('tbody').stop().animate({scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('tbody').animate({
  scrollTop: $('tbody').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
}, 500);
```